# How would I provide full mailbox access permissions using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: graph, office365

I would like to get a list of mailboxes a user has access to using Microsoft Graph.

I know this is doable through PowerShell via the following:

`Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User "UserAccount@Company.com"`

But how would I achieve this using Microsoft Graph? I would imagine there is a method but I can't find it.